# Confusion with Fermi energy in Quantum Hall effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, electronic-band-theory, fermi-energy

It is well-known, that when someone turn on magnetic field, and if magnetic field large enough, only few Landau levels are filled:

[image]

But I can't understand what going on with Fermi energy.

Fermi energy is defined as minimal energy of electron, to be added to system.

But when we turn on magnetic field, electrons sit at Landau levels, and energy of this levels are smaller than initial Fermi energy. So it seems that we can add electrons with smaller energy, then initial Fermi energy.

Why Fermi energy remains the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. If the $n^{th}$ Landau level is not fully filled, one would expect the Fermi energy to be between the energy of the $n^{th}$ and $(n+1)^{th}$ Landau levels. I guess the above picture just gives a specific instance for a magnetic field $B_{0}$ where the $n=0,1,2$ levels are fully filled, and hence the Fermi energy lies between the energies of 2nd and 3rd Landau levels.